# bigger UISlider ok but tracking zone problem

Tags: iphone, uislider

My goal is to create a bigger UISlider with 35 pixels height for the thumb image.

I subclassed UISlider and added the method :

```
- (CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width, 50);
}
```

Then I set the thum image from my controller using setThumbImage:

My bigger thumb is well displayed.

The problem I have is that the tracking zone is still the same around 19 px height, how to extend it to 50 ?

Thanks

T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you may want to look at `thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:`

Comment: Unfortunately, UISlider doesn't use the return from this function to determine the touch region of the slider thumb.

Comment: how to call thumbRectForBounds method, is it UISlider Delegate method ?

Answer (score 32):

A long-standing problem with the iPhone OS' UISlider control is that you can't make it taller. More specifically, you can make it look taller by specifying taller images for its thumb and track, but the touch area stays as a tiny 23px tall.

[Michael Patricios has published a way](http://mpatric.blogspot.com/2009/04/more-responsive-sliders-on-iphone.html) to make the default sliders a lot easier to touch, and a variation of that technique can handle larger sliders. What you need to do is subclass UISlider, and override pointInside in your class:

```
// How many extra touchable pixels you want above and below the 23px slider
#define SIZE_EXTENSION_Y 10

- (BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    bounds = CGRectInset(bounds, 0, SIZE_EXTENSION_Y);
    return CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, point);
}
```

In Interface Builder, set the slider to use your new UISlider subclass, and you now have a slider with a 43px touchable height.

Comment: Small correction: I think you want to pass a negative SIZE_EXTENSION_Y value to CGRectInset to make the rect larger.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! With a setting of -10 this worked perfectly! I was trying to solve this problem myself for some time, and this worked beautifully.

Comment: Think it doesn't work anymore in iOS 5. Value of 100 for example has no effect. Tried both positive and negative.

Comment: It still has an effect for me in iOS5, but the results are unpredictable. Even at -1, the area that can be touched is very large, much larger than I need them to be, but I can't get much smaller than 1, so not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 11):

I'm using this solution :)

```
CGRect sliderFrame = self.mySlider.frame;    
sliderFrame.size.height = 142.0; 
[self.mySlider setFrame:sliderFrame];
```

Comment: this solution seems way simpler than @Allen Pike's one. It seems to be working too. Is there a reason that his answer is prefered over yours ?

Comment: This does work but it also offsets the slider vertically, but that's easy enough to fix.

Comment: @alexhajdu so this way you are not subclassing UISlider is that correct? I can't fix this using your answer

Comment: Yes, its solution with no subclassing. Did you got some errors?

Answer (score 9):

Increase UISlider thumb hit area by increasing the height of the UISlider frame. This approach avoids any offset and subsequent need to correct the slider frame.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //expand slider hit area
    self.slider.frame = CGRectInset(self.slider.frame, 0, -10);

}
```

Comment: This answer is much easier than the two above. Works great. Thanks!